# How to include custom JS (AOS.js specifically) in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker, aos.js

I'm new to Rails 6 + Webpack, so bear with me.

I'm trying to load `aos.js` into Rails 6, and then call it from a view file.

I've created `javascript/custom/aos.js` which contains [this code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.js) with the following snippet appended:

`console.log("typeof(AOS): " + typeof(AOS))`

My `application.js` is here:

```
require("jquery")
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require("custom/aos") // <===== The custom file I'm importing

var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

When I load my page, I get:

`typeof(AOS): undefined` so I know the file is being included, but AOS remains undefined.

However, when I include a `javascript_include_tag` with the CDN link, or simply paste the CDN code into the console, AOS is defined and everything works fine.

**Why is AOS undefined when I require it in application.js?** Thanks for your help!

Comment: At first glance at that file, AOS does not appear to be a local variable to the scope of the module; it's an export. Try `const AOS = require('custom/aos')` in the pack file instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use YARN to install the package instead.

```
$ yarn add aos
```

And then import it in your own script where you use AOS:

```
// app/javascripts/pesky_scrolly_stuff.js
import AOS from 'aos';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  AOS.init({
    startEvent: 'turbolinks:load' // if you are using turbolinks
  });
});
```

And require your script into the pack:

```
// app/javascripts/packs/application.js
require("pesky_scrolly_stuff")
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for the explanation. I was trying to access `AOS` from the view itself. I guess webpack is not scoping AOS to `window`--any idea how to make `AOS` accessible from a view?

Comment: Explicitly assign it to window. `window.AOS = require('aos');`. But then again you can just avoid shooting yourself in the foot by NOT putting JS in your views.